# How to install openssl1.0.1 alongside the the default system openssl? (Centos/redhat)

Tags: linux, centos, openssl

I was tasked to setup openssl alongside the default version installed on the system.

I want to know how I can set this up?

I would like to point apache to use the portable version of openssl (I am sure I can figure that out -- but if you feel generous).

Are there any risks with this setup?

Comment: Grab the source build and install into `/usr/local/`.  Then grab the source for apache and build and compile into `/usr/local/`, then recompile all the things linked to apache, again put them in `/usr/local/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the `INSTALL` file:

```
$ ./config --prefix=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl
```

replace the optional locations with your own.

Can't think of any risks other than cumbersome to manage in the long run and you will need to setup your startup scripts accordingly to obtain the shared libs in all other programs.

Comment: Thank you.. That worked. I was using these flags "--libdir=lib shared zlib-dynamic" along with your flags in your answer.